# Nativescript 8 IOS shadow cornerRadius bug

Tags: ios, nativescript, shadow, border-radius

[image]

Here is an example with test shadow (black) for element(white) with cornerRadius 17dpi
But the shadow takes on a radius that is larger than the element it belongs to and visually it looks like the shadow becomes cornerRadius 50% but should be 17 dpi.

Expected result: the cornerRadius on the shadow should match the cornerRadius on the element

This is reproduced in the case of applying a shadow through styles:

```
box-shadow: 0 20 0 #000;
```

To element with:

```
border-radius: 17;
```

package.json

```
"@nativescript/core": "8.3.6",
"@nativescript/ios": "8.2.3",
```

If you apply the shadow directly, it works as it should

```
const nsView = args.object;
const nsColorShadow = new Color('black');
const nsColorBg = new Color('white');

const iosView = nsView.ios;

iosView.layer.masksToBounds = false;
iosView.layer.shadowColor = nsColorShadow.ios.CGColor;
iosView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
iosView.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
iosView.layer.cornerRadius = 17;
iosView.layer.backgroundColor = nsColorBg.ios.CGColor;
iosView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is fix in core@8.4.2 https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/10142

Answer (score 1):

`iosView.layer.cornerRadius` is in dp (device pixels), not dip (device independent pixels). When you're setting `border-radius: 17;` you're setting in dip. You could also set it as `border-radius: 17px;` to get the same result as you had on the manual setting of the view.

The reason you're seeing it stuck at 50% is because 50% is the max value for border-radius, and 17dip converted to dp will be larger than 50%, so it'll clip to 50%.